# Changing highlight color of the 'Outline View' in Eclipse on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, colors

In Eclipse, the highlight color in the 'Outline View' is so close to the normal color I can't see it.  I know you can change the text editor quite a bit but I don't see a way to change colors of the other views including the Outline View.  I have also tried to change the system colors or Windows 7 but nothing seems to specifically change the highlight color.  Is this something that is configurable or maybe something a plugin might already do?

Comment: I agree. It is so faint it is hardly highlighted at all. One workaround is to change the theme to a dark one. Although that doesn't really help if you prefer light themes.

Comment: I spose you could also modify the contrast settings on the monitor.

Comment: I have spent ages messing with the appearance of Aptana themes, Windows themes, my monitor settings trying to make Aptana Studio 3's highlights in the Outline Window more noticeable. However, I think the main cause of the issue is that, for some weird reason, the highlight of a php function gets lost when the cursor moves into the scope of an `if` condition. Because of this I was altering settings trying to see a highlight that simply wasn't there. This might be a bug in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't Eclipse-specific and there is not going to be a plugin to control this. The Outline View uses Windows native tree widget. You will need to keep looking at Windows configuration to see if you can alter this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that answers it!  BTW, I have played around with every setting I know of and there doesn't seem to be any in Windows 7 for this.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Saved a lot of my time faffing about trying to fix this unfixable issue.